# moment is not defined when upgrading from 2.1.0 to 2.29.1

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

Our code base is using moment 2.1.0 in a browser, loading a js file that has the js source code https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.1.0/moment.min.js

define it like that (it works)

```
define(
        ["jquery","bootstrap", "moment"],
    function ($) {})
```

When upgrading moment to the latest version (2.29.1 with source code from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js ) so we can use moment-timezone we are getting

```
moment is not defined
```

what is missing?